# How to update data in SQL (Execute query) with AJAX in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I want to pass data with AJAX and execute an update query with PHP.

This is an admin hospital application. I already tried **this code (below) but it did not execute the query.**

This is 'pasien.php':

```
$('button[name="hapus-wali-button"]').click(function(){
            let kodeWali = $(this).attr("id");
            console.log(kodeWali);
            $('#deleteWaliModal').modal("show");
            document.getElementById("hapusWaliButton").onclick = function(){
                console.log(kodeWali);
                $.ajax({
                    url:'hapus-wali.php',
                    method:'get',
                    data: {kodeWali:kodeWali},
                    success:function(response){
                        if(response == 1){
                            $("#"+kode).remove();
                            window.location.reload(true);
                        }else{
                            alert('Invalid');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

I want to click a button, take the id value (the id is the data I want to pass), and then show a warning modal.
After I click the 'confirm' button, I want to send the id value (kodeWali) to the 'hapus-wali.php' and do some query.

This is 'hapus-wali.php':

```php
<?php
    require '../function.php';
    $id = $_GET["kodeWali"];
    $sqlDeleteWali = "UPDATE pasien SET kd_wali = '' WHERE kd_pasien = '$id'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sqlDeleteWali);
    header('Location:pasien.php');
?>
```

This is 'function.php':

```php
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "db-sirs-final";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if(!$conn){
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>
```

Why does it throw the error response "Invalid"?

Comment: This might be useful: https://makitweb.com/how-to-delete-record-from-mysql-table-with-ajax/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.click() handler reloading page instead of triggering event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465599/click-handler-reloading-page-instead-of-triggering-event) also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249563/jquery-click-event-reloads-the-page)

Comment: Why do you expect `response == 1` to be true?  `response` would be the output of the PHP script, and right now, you aren't producing any output.

Comment: @PatrickQ I add ```echo 1``` at the PHP script. Still Invalid.